# Applescript and Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, applescript

I would like to call a IBAction within a cocoa app from applescript:

I want to call:

```
    - (IBAction)reverse:(id)pId;
    {
        direction = -1;

    }
```

with a line in an external applescript file like:

```
    tell application "theapp"
    reverse
    end tell
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSAppleScript.

```
NSAppleScript *as = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"theapp\"\nreverse\nend tell"];
NSDictionary *err = nil;
NSAppleEventDescriptor *desc = [as executeAndReturnError:&err];
NSLog(@"Error: %@\nData: %@", err, desc.data);
[as release];
```

There is also a good answer about `Scripting Bridge` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987943/applescript-inside-of-a-cocoa-application)