# Is it possible to update the "watched" flag of a video in the iTunes library through Xcode?

Tags: ituneslibrary

I am looking to create an App that allows me to play my iTunes Library files, however I want it to update the status of the video (e.g., watched or time remaining).  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your app runs on MacOS, you can send an Apple Event to change the watched flag, or the time remaining.  You could also write an AppleScript that does this and then have your code run the AppleScript.

Check out: [Applescript Inside of a Cocoa Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987943/applescript-inside-of-a-cocoa-application)  And also Google sending Apple Events from C or Objective C